# Rational fractions as geometric predicates

Tags: geometry, functions, analytic-geometry, rational-functions

I read article about restricted voronoi diagram. In chapter 3.4 Exact predicates I saw the following: "sideA, sideB, sideC are rational fractions of low-degree (resp. 2, 4/2 and 6/4)." sideA - should return side of point from plane. How rational fraction can help in this problem? Rational fraction and rational function are the same?

Link to the article https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00547790/document

Comment: I don't understand your question isolated from the rest of this huge text. Why having a fraction $6/4$ like $(at^6+...)/(a't^4+...)$ would be more an issue that all the rest of the text ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I have 3 points: x1, x2, q. x1 and x2 define plane with point (x1 + x2) * 0.5 and normal x1 - x2. Function sideA (x1, x2, q)  should return side of point q from plane. But sideA - rational fraction of degree 2. What does it mean?